# Prevent macOS generic keyboard driver from capturing usb-device

Tags: c, macos, usb, kernel-extension

I'm trying to write a macOS user-level driver in C for a usb-device (a pentablet with buttons).

Currently this tablet gets recognized as generic mouse and generic keyboard from the system. Since the shortcuts applied to the buttons of the pentablet are not customizeable, I'd like to write my own driver for that.

**What's working:**

I am able to read the raw-data with hidapi (http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/) from the device, which looks something like this:

```
A   B    C    D    E    F    G    H
10  192  228  50   157  43   0    0
```

I figured out, that when I use the pen the values of the columns `B-H` change according to the pens position, pressure and click.

**My problem:**

However, I cannot figure out how to access the buttons of the device. Each time I press one of them, their hardcoded key-combination gets triggered. Since the values of column `A` never change, I assume that the device is still captured as a generic keyboard by the system, and so this column never shows me the currently pressed button and triggers it's key-combination.

Each time I press one of these buttons they **all trigger a holding ALT/Option + Shift**, additionally some of them trigger a character, and one of them triggers the volume up.

So, my approach was to use a codeless kext for preventing the system from capturing the device. But this doesn't work either - the device still gets captured by the system as a generic keyboard.

I disabled `csrutil` and with `kextload`, having my kext located in `/Library/Extensions`, I get a successfull message, that the kext is loaded:

```
Warnings:
    Personality CFBundleIdentifier differs from containing kext's (not necessarily a mistake, but rarely done):
        Tablet

Code Signing Failure: code signature is invalid
Warnings:
    Personality CFBundleIdentifier differs from containing kext's (not necessarily a mistake, but rarely done):
        Tablet

/Library/Extensions/foobartablet.kext appears to be loadable (not including linkage for on-disk libraries).
kext-dev-mode allowing invalid signature -67050 0xFFFFFFFFFFFEFA16 for kext "/Library/Extensions/foobartablet.kext"
kext signature failure override allowing invalid signature -67050 0xFFFFFFFFFFFEFA16 for kext "/Library/Extensions/foobartablet.kext"
Loading /Library/Extensions/foobartablet.kext.
```

Here's my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>13C64</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>1.0 Copyright © Adis Durakovic</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.adisdurakovic.huitablet</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>KEXT</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>Huion Tablet 1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>5A2053</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>GM</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>13A595</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>macosx10.9</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>0501</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>5A2053</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Tablet</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.kpi.iokit</string>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>IOService</string>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOUSBDevice</string>
            <key>idVendor</key>
            <string>9580</string>
            <key>idProduct</key>
            <string>110</string>
            <key>bcdDevice</key>
            <string>12288</string>
            <key>IOProbeScore</key>
            <integer>200000</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>TabletNew</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.kpi.iokit</string>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>IOService</string>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOUSBHostDevice</string>
            <key>idVendor</key>
            <string>9580</string>
            <key>idProduct</key>
            <string>110</string>
            <key>bcdDevice</key>
            <string>12288</string>
            <key>IOProbeScore</key>
            <integer>300000</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
    <dict/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And here's also my `ioreg -i -w 0 -l -n "PenTablet"` output which I used for device matching:
https://adisdurakovic.com/pentablet.txt

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible the device is simulating another interface for the buttons so that they can be read in as separate input?

Comment: @Nick, any hint for me how I could investigate further in this direction?

Comment: To be honest, I'm far more experienced with a pure Linux environment device wise. I only commented because I had a similar issue once with a device that had two USB logical interfaces so that it's buttons could be seen as a generic keyboard input. In Linux I would compare the contents of the USB dev files with the device unplugged vs plugged in to see the devices. I'm not sure about MacOS. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: @Nick It's still a very helpful input. Maybe further researches could lead me towards your suggestion. Thank you anyway for your help, I appreciate that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention SIP, I assume you're testing this on 10.11 or newer. Your `IOProviderClass` is set to `IOUSBDevice` - this will only work for 10.10 and older. 10.11 introduced a completely new USB stack, the new class name is `IOUSBHostDevice`. I know that's not what IORegistryExplorer/`ioreg` say: there's a translation going on somewhere to keep old userspace apps ticking over. In the kernel, drivers matching `IOUSBHostDevice` will take precedence over those matching `IOUSBDevice`. If you want to support both, you can just add an extra personality to your codeless kext. For kexts *with* code, you'll need to create two versions of your kext if the legacy support doesn't work in your case.

Another thing that could affect it is probe score, although in theory your *idVendor + idProduct + bcdDevice* rule should already have a very high score.

Comment: You're right, currently I'm testing on macOS 10.12. I added another personality, changing `IOUSBDevice` to `IOUSBHostDevice` but this doesn't work either. The device still gets completely captured by the system.

Comment: @ad_on_is Can you update the `ioreg` output in your question with 1. what you get if you re-run it with the -i option added? 2. The service that successfully matches the device, in addition to the device node itself? There are a few more possibilities here, including probe score - have you experimented with that?

Comment: Updated the `ioreg` as requested. Additionally I updated the info.plist with the modified `IOProbeScore`. Since I'm fairly new to driver development, and this one is just a hobby-side project, I don't exactly now what your 2. point exactly means. Do you have some more hints for me?

Comment: Some questions that I ask myself are: Is my approach even right? Should a codeless kext, if matched and loaded successfully, prevent the device from being recognised as an generic input (mouse and keyboard)? Will I then be able to read the raw input from that device and use it in my C-code to operate mouse and keyboard-inputs on user-level? I'm also aware that the finished driver has to have accessibility-rights in "Security & Privacy" settings to fully operate.

Comment: Can you also show the *clients* of your device? I want to see what's currently matching the device. Try something like: `ioreg -i -r -w 0 -l -n "PenTablet "` (Assuming that's the device you're after.) For your second question: if I understand what you're trying to do correctly, then yes, you're on the right track. (Although you may not want to match the USB device directly, just one of the HID interfaces.) What I'm not 100% clear on is exactly what happens *currently* when you press one of the buttons you want to program. With that info + the ioreg output I should be able to tell.

Comment: Updated my question. I had to remove the `-r` option since it results in an empty output. The behaviour is as follows: Each time I press one of these buttons they **all trigger a holding ALT/Option + Shift**, additionally some of them trigger a character, and one of them triggers the volume up.

Comment: OK, interesting. I'll check out the ioreg output in detail tomorrow and let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: Great. Thank you in advance ;-)

Comment: Hey @pmdj, did you find some time to check my ioreg output? I still haven't solved the problem :-(